# Как адаптировать сайт под кол-во контента?

Tags: css3

Как адаптировать сайт под кол-во контента? При добавлении контента страница не растягивается вниз

```css
/*******Основа********/

body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #00BFFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}


/********Блок заголовка*******/

.header {
  height: 200px;
  /*    border: 2px solid blue;*/
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
}


/********Блок навигации********/

.nav {
  width: 998px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #B0E0E6;
  position: relative;
  background: #3CB371;
}

.menu_ul {
  align-content: center;
}

.menu_li {
  list-style: none;
  /*убираем маркеры списка*/
  display: inline;
  /*делаем элементы списка горизонтальными*/
  padding: 16px 58px 16px 58px;
  /*    border-radius: 88px 88px 0px 0px;    */
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.menu_li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(224, 255, 255, .5);
  transition: .3s linear;
}

a {
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*убираем подчеркивание текста ссылок*/
  color: #909090;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

.menu_li:hover a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


/********Контент*****/

.sect {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}


/*******Футер*******/

.foot {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #002000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-------Заголовок сайта------->
<header class="header">
  Заголовок
</header>
<!-- Навигация -->
<nav class="nav">
  <!--        <h3>навигация</h3>-->
  <ul class="menu_ul">
    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">ПУНКТ1</a></li>
    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">ПУНКТ2</a></li>
    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">ПУНКТ3</a></li>
    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">ПУНКТ4</a></li>
    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">ПУНКТ5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!------Основной контент------>
<section class="section">
  <div class="sect">
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>
    <p>Попробуйте изменить размер окна: вы увидите, что каждое предложение находится на одной строке, когда окно достаточно широкое. Только тогда, когда окно слишком узкое для всего предложения, это предложение будет разбито на несколько строк. Когда вы
      удалите правило 'margin-right: -50%' и снова измените размер окна, вы заметите, что предложения будут уже разбиты, хотя окно все еще шире строк текста в два раза.
    </p>

  </div>
</section>
<!------Подвал сайта------->
<footer class="foot">
  ПОДВАЛ
</footer>
```

Comment: лучше всего добавляйте код сразу в сниппет этого сайта, нежели ссылкой.

Comment: хорошо........)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не до конца понятен, конечно. Но... 
Ты можешь использовать свойство min-height. 
Если вопрос в футере, который накладывается на контент, то это из-за position: absolute.

Comment: Нужно, что бы при добавлении нового контента футер шёл вниз...

Comment: Чтобы футер не накладывался на контент?

Comment: да...что бы он всегда уходил вниз, при добавлении новых строчек текста например и тем самым растягивалась страница по вертикали.

Comment: Просто удали строчку position: absolute

Comment: Спасибо) Я ни как с position не могу разобраться..